# Tornado: returning a value from callback

Tags: python, tornado, yield

Suppose I have a JSON-RPC handler in Tornado. In that handler is a function called start_connection, in which a websocket connection is made. How can I return a message when the connection succeeds, and return another message when the connection fails.

I tried this:

```
class MainHandler(JSONRPCHandler):

    def start_connection(self, uuid, addr):
        try:
            def store_connection(future):
                conn = future.result()
                # store conn
                return {'success': True}

            websocket.websocket_connect(addr, io_loop=main_loop, callback=store_connection)

        except Exception, e:
            return {'success': False, 'error_message': str(e)}
```

But this doesn't work because the success message is not returned from `start_connection`, but from the callback. I also tried to use the `gen.coroutine` decorator and adding the `yield` keyword before `websocket_connect`, but this resulted in an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1115, in _stack_context_handle_exception
    raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1298, in wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornadorpc/tornadorpc/base.py", line 259, in post
    self._RPC_.run(self, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornadorpc/tornadorpc/base.py", line 103, in run
    self.dispatch(request[0], request[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornadorpc/tornadorpc/base.py", line 145, in dispatch
    final_kwargs, extra_args = getcallargs(method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornadorpc/tornadorpc/utils.py", line 23, in getcallargs
    self_key = args.pop(0)
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Tornado, but let me try.

Isn't the whole idea of a callback in an async server that it will be called LATER, a noticable time after [`websocket_connect()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html) exits?

I believe you'll have to handle results in the callback itself, or do something like

```
future = websocket.websocket_connect( \
   addr, io_loop=main_loop, callback=store_connection)
```

and

```
future.add_done_callback(some_completion_callback)
```

or, rather, recommended for Tornado by [add_done_callback()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/concurrent.html) doc, use [IOLoop.add_future()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_future):

```
main_loop.add_future(future, some_completion_callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I had to use tornadorpc's async decorator as described here: https://github.com/joshmarshall/tornadorpc#asynchronous-example